# Git - How do I log the current branch name AND the last remote URL I pushed to into the console

Tags: git, alias

I want to create a git alias (or bash alias) that will print out (into the console) the currently checked out branch & also the last remote (url not name) that it was pushed to.

Ideally I want it to work like this:

```
> git log-branch-fork
Branch Name: features/current_feature_name
Form URL: git@github.io:UserName/ForkUrl.git
```

Alternatively, I could pass in a parameter which contains the `name` of the remote:

```
> git log-branch-fork my-fork
Branch Name: features/current_feature_name
Form URL: git@github.io:UserName/my-fork.git
```

Comment: IIRC, git does not track where a branch was last pushed too. It knows about the tracking remote if you've configured it, but you'd have to track and store the pushed-to remote yourself.

Comment: yea I figured as much, so I thought I could use a parameter containing the remote name

Answer (score 1):

> the last remote (url not name) that it was pushed to.

This cannot be determined completely reliably as Git doesn't store information regarding when pushes occur.

But, by looking at the current branch's *tracking branch* we can at least see the `remote` that Git uses when `git-push` is invoked without explicitly using the `remote` argument.

Here is a shell script which uses the tracking branch to determine the associated `remote` branch. You can also optionally pass in a `remote`:

```
#!/bin/sh

# get full tracking branch name
# (e.g origin/master)
BR=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name @{u}`

# either get remote from user
# or from parsing the tracking branch's name
if [ $# -eq 1 ]
  then
    REMOTE=$1
else
  REMOTE=`echo $BR | cut -d/ -f 1`
fi

# get url associated with remote
URL=`git config --get remote.$REMOTE.url`

# print out results
echo "Branch Name: $BR"
echo "From URL: $URL"
```

I would recommend putting this script on your `PATH` and then when your current working directory is within a Git repo invoke it just by specifying it's name (and optionally passing in the `remote`).